# How can I average two orthogonal spaces and retain orthonormality?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthonormal

Lets assume we have two "spaces" each characterised by a set of orthogonal basis functions. How can one "average" the spaces. That is to say find a third space, which is also orthogonal. I have considered the following:

vector space one with two basis.

$V^1_1, V^1_2$

These are orthonormal:

$V^1_1\cdot V^1_1 = 1$

$V^1_2\cdot V^1_2 = 1$

$V^1_2\cdot V^1_1 = V^1_1\cdot V^1_2 = 0$

We also consider a second vector space

$V^2_1, V^2_2$

These are orthonormal:

$V^2_1\cdot V^2_1 = 1$

$V^2_2\cdot V^2_2 = 1$

$V^2_2\cdot V^2_1 = V^2_1V^2_2 = 0$

Let us attempt to take the average of these vectors:

$V^3_1 = {1\over2}\left(V^1_1+V^2_1\right)$

$V^3_2 = {1\over2}\left(V^1_2+V^2_2\right)$

Then we consider the dot products of this new space:

$
\begin{align}
V^3_1 \cdot V^3_1 & = {1\over2}\left(V^1_1+V^2_1\right) \cdot {1\over2}\left(V^1_1+V^2_1\right) \\
& = {1\over4} \left( V^1_1 \cdot V^1_1 + V^2_1 \cdot V^2_1 + V^1_1 \cdot V^2_1 + V^2_1  \cdot  V^1_1\right) \\
& = {1\over2} \left(1+\text{cos}\theta_{V^2_1,V^1_1}\right) \\
\end{align}
$
By using the above orthogonalities and the cosine angle rule. Now to retain orthogonality one could weight $V^3_1$ by the square root of this. Next consider

$
\begin{align}
V^3_1 \cdot V^3_2 & = {1\over2}\left(V^1_1+V^2_1\right) \cdot {1\over2}\left(V^1_2+V^2_2\right) \\
& = {1\over4} \left( V^1_1 \cdot V^1_2 + V^2_1 \cdot V^2_2 + V^1_1 \cdot V^2_2 + V^2_1  \cdot  V^1_2\right) \\
& = {1\over4} \left( \text{cos}\theta_{V^2_1,V^1_2}+\text{cos}\theta_{V^1_1,V^2_2}\right) \\
\end{align}
$
This is however not zero unless $\theta_{V^2_1,V^1_2} = - \theta_{V^1_1,V^2_2}$. So how can I average two orthogonal spaces and retain orthonormality?

Comment: Please try to formulate your question more rigorously. Given two subspaces of a vector space that are orthogonal, it is not always possible to find a nontrivial third space that is also orthogonal. An easy example for this would be when $V = V_1 \bigoplus V_2$

Comment: You could search for a permutation matrix mapping one eigensystem to the other minimizing the pairwise distances of eigenvectors. A reasonable heuristic for this could probably be an iterated reweighted linear system optimizing a matrix multiplication encouraging values to be 0 or 1 and sum to 1. Then when found the permutation pairing the eigenvectors up, you could search for new vectors being candidate eigenvectors of your new system trying to minimize some weighted distance between the two systems after permutation.